# copy/paste a range of data from non contiguous to non-contiguous columns in a different worksheet based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

So following the prious question ([VBA migrating data from different worksheets to one worksheet at specific locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135104/vba-migrating-data-from-different-worksheets-to-one-worksheet-at-specific-locati)) I have edited the code to the following below based on posts from other code researchers/experts.

The previous codes (see link) were working up to a certain point where a running time error would come up. I have followed the suggestions and removed .Select. and .Activate from the copy/paste operations however currently the code below does not do anything from the point 'copy from feedstock records sheet' onwards. I am sure I am doing something wrong or that I could approach my problem in a different way but I am struggling to find a solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

After debugging I have managed to overcome the error 13 which was related to cells though defined as date the order of date was messed up and once I changed the order of the cells it was ok. However I know have the error 1004 as decribed in the comments below (see my last comment). I was wondering if anyone has any approche on how to solve this issue. I have marked where the error appears (it's on the second loop). in sht5 the date only starts on 01/01/2015 however sht4 starts on 07/08/2014. After I fixed the problem on the first days in 2014 the code was able to run until it reached the value 01/01/2015 when past special the range specified in **bold** below. Could anyone help? Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

'open/close worksheets from huddle folder and teamviewer'

Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim Wb3 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Dim sht4 As Worksheet
Dim sht5 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow3 As Long
Dim monthsi As Date, monthsk As Date, monthsj As Date

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("U:\Data from plants\Huddle\EEL Feedstock Records -  NEW VERSION.xlsx")
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("U:\Data from plants\Teamviewer\EE.xlsx")
Set Wb3 = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = Wb1.Sheets("Feedstock Usage (Non-beet site)")
Set sht2 = Wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht3 = Wb3.Sheets("Feedstock records")
Set sht4 = Wb3.Sheets("Teamviewer")
Set sht5 = Wb3.Sheets("Plants data")

sht3.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
sht4.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp

sht1.Cells.Copy
sht3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Wb1.Close False

sht2.Cells.Copy
sht4.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Wb2.Close False


'copy from feedstock records sheet'
lastrow1 = sht3.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 10
lastrow2 = sht4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
k = 4
lastrow3 = sht5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
j = 5

Do
    monthsi = sht3.Cells(i, "C").Value
    If sht5.Cells(j, "A").Value = monthsi Then
    sht3.Range(Cells(i, "D"), Cells(i, "E")).Copy
    sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VE"), Cells(j, "VF")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sht3.Range(Cells(i, "G"), Cells(i, "H")).Copy
    sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VI"), Cells(j, "VJ")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sht3.Range(Cells(i, "J"), Cells(i, "K")).Copy
    sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VM"), Cells(j, "VN")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sht3.Range(Cells(i, "M"), Cells(i, "N")).Copy
    sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VY"), Cells(j, "VZ")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sht3.Range(Cells(i, "P"), Cells(i, "Q")).Copy
    sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VQ"), Cells(j, "VR")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = lastrow1 + 1

Do
monthsk = sht4.Cells(k, "A").Value

    If sht5.Cells(j, "A").Value = monthsk Then
     sht4.Cells(k, "H").Copy
     sht5.Cells(j, "XW").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     sht4.Cells(k, "I").Copy
     sht5.Cells(j, "YJ").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     sht4.Range(Cells(k, "J"), Cells(k, "O")).Copy
     **sht5.Range(Cells(j, "ZK"), Cells(j, "ZP")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues**
     sht4.Cells(k, "U").Copy
     sht5.Cells(j, "XU").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     sht4.Cells(k, "X").Copy
     sht5.Cells(j, "XV").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     sht4.Cells(k, "Y").Copy
     sht5.Cells(j, "YH").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     sht4.Cells(k, "AB").Copy
     sht5.Cells(j, "YI").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     sht4.Range(Cells(k, "AN"), Cells(i, "AP")).Copy
     sht5.Range(Cells(j, "XR"), Cells(j, "XT")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     sht4.Cells(k, "AQ").Copy
     sht5.Cells(j, "XQ").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     End If
     k = k + 1
Loop Until k = lastrow2 + 1

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I notice in both `Loop Until` statements you have `j = lastrow3 + 1`, but I don't see where you are incrementing `j` in your loops.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want to bring the setting of `monthsi`, `monthsj` and `monthsk` inside your loops. You increase `i` in the first loop for example, but that doesn't change `monthsi`, so if the comparison is false to begin with, the if statement will never run.

For example, the first loop would become:

```
Do
    monthsi = sht3.Cells(i, "C").Value
    If monthsj = monthsi Then
        sht3.Range(Cells(i, "D"), Cells(i, "E")).Copy
        sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VA"), Cells(j, "VB")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sht3.Range(Cells(i, "G"), Cells(i, "H")).Copy
        sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VE"), Cells(j, "VF")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sht3.Range(Cells(i, "J"), Cells(i, "K")).Copy
        sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VI"), Cells(j, "VJ")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sht3.Range(Cells(i, "M"), Cells(i, "N")).Copy
        sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VM"), Cells(j, "VN")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sht3.Range(Cells(i, "P"), Cells(i, "Q")).Copy
        sht5.Range(Cells(j, "VQ"), Cells(j, "VR")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = lastrow1 + 1 Or j = lastrow3 + 1
```

This still leaves the question raised by PartyHatPanda of why you are checking against `j` to end the loop when `j` isn't changing, so there may be a deeper error in your logic. ie if `j` should be increasing as well, then the assignment of `monthsj` should also be brought into the loop in the same way.

Comment: Tried but get run time error 13 on "monthsk = sht4.Cells(k, "A").Value"

Comment: That's a [Type mismatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx), so it sounds like not all of the values in column A of sht4 are dates.

Comment: how would you suggest to bring the setting monthsi, monthsj and monthsk inside the loop? I might be doing something wrong...

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Thats how I was doing...Still getting error 13. @PartyHatPanda I guess it should not increase it will only be increasing as a result of i. so I removed that bit. I just don't understand the error on that statement now (monthsi=sht3.Cells(i, "C").value) after "Do".

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce that I'm afraid - the code works for me so it does sound like a data issue. Have you tried debugging? What is the type of `sht3.Cells(i, "C").value` when it falls over?

Comment: I am away and only be able to check that on Monday. I have to learn a bit how to do debugging properly..I'll let you know. thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks @bobajob I have been deugging the code and yes you were right. The cells on sht4 though defined as date the order was messed up. The error 13 I was getting had to do with this. However, I am still debugging the code because now I have the error "1004 Method range of object worksheet failed". The error seems to fall when doing the operation paste special in on sht5 where the value is "Application defined or object defined error". I edited the code above. Do you have any suggestions on how to approache this error. Thanks in advance